# FormClosing event fires twice after using exit button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button for exiting the form and this is the code

```
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Program?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I tried using debugger mode, and after I click yes, it goes through Application.Exit() and then fires up the FormClosing event then running the same dialog.

I also tried deleting the code in FormClosing event so it only has Application.Exit() but using Alt+F4 or clicking the X button will exit the application automatically.

My question is how can I question the user if he wants to exit the program but not firing the dialog twice?

Thanks in advance, and I'm letting you all know I'm just a beginner and this is my biggest project so I want to make this great.

Comment: This question is a little unclear: Is the code you posted in the button handler, in the `FormClosed` handler or in both? Please show the `FormClosed` handler if it's different. If it's the same, well the problem would be obvious.

Comment: Add a check on the [CloseReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [FormClosingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) object that is passed to you. If it is `ApplicationExitCall`, don't show the dialog.

Comment: they have the same code, then i tried deleting the code and only the Application.Exit remained, then I run the program and click the X or Close button, it automatically closes, no dialog

Comment: Check the event arg that describes the cause of the form close event.

Comment: IMHO, apps that ask to confirm closing seem annoying to me, unless in some use cases where there is unsaved data lingering, which I don't see in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

- By unsubscribe the even on button click
- As suggested in stuartd's answer, checking reason of closing ***(but there is a problem in his answer so adding this approach too with fix, so it will help future people.)***

I am assuming, As you need this confirmation in both cases,  button click and 'x' button click, you have put the same code in both handler.

**Approach one**

In the handler of button click, while you are asking for user confirmation and if user is clicking 'yes'.
Before the line,

```
Application.Exit();
```

you should unsubscribe the Form closing event. By doing this, It must not raise form closing event while performing Application.Exit()

assuming your form is MainForm and event is MainForm_Closing, it would look like,

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Program?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.FormClosing -= MainForm_FormClosing;
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

so it will not raise form closing event while performing `Application.Exit()` and thus your problem will be solved.

**Approach Two**

As stuartd has suggested (which is more cleaner way according to me. +1 for that), you can check for form closing reason in `Form Closing` event handler.

**Note** that there is a little problem (bug) in his sample code [which you have already accepted as an answer!!]. After clicking `'x' button` or `Alt+F4` by mistake; if user clicks on 'No' on the confirmation message, then too form is being closed because there is no handling for else condition. Proper solution should be like below.

```
        private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Program?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    Application.Exit();
                else
                    e.Cancel = true;    //stopping Form Close perocess.
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried unsubscribing the event, but using Alt+F4 or clicking X button will show any dialog for confirmation

Comment: what do you mean Any Dialog? if it is the same you have placed in Form closing event, after unsubscribing event. It should not be shown.

Comment: i only have 1 object, it is the dialogresult

Comment: As i have edited in my answer, are you unsubscribing the event in Button's click event before Application.Exit?

Comment: @JonathanTapnio I have put proper formatted answer + **a fix in accepted answer.** Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example. It only asks for confirmation if the close was initiated by the user - you probably don't want a MessageBox popping up when Windows is restarting.

```
private void form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Program?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // Cancel the close
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
 }
```